# Hyperlink in pentaho cde table component

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have created a table component in Pentaho in which I add a column with a hyperlink of the format `https://www.aaaa.com/id`.
It correctly shows in the table.

Now I want to create another hyperlink in the same table, but it has format 
`https://www.aaaa.com/probe&bbbbb%20&bbb$probe2`.

How can I make it show only the field and not the path?

I have achieved something similar but clicking anywhere in the row the page is opened while I want it to only open the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write a function under click Action under advance property something like below.
tableData[e.rowIdx][1] is a column name where you have to specify the column where you have to specify the click event.

```
function testClick(e) {
var id = e.tableData[e.rowIdx][1];
window.open('/pentaho/api/repos/%3Apublic%3Asample%3Adashboards%3Aname.wcdf/generatedContent?p_site='+id,"_self");

}
```

also you can write CSS to put underline and hover change color.

also put below code for all the table columns where you don't want click event.

```
#tbl_waste_overviewTable tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried that. Works correctly. The problem with that is that it takes me to the link by clicking on the indicated column or on any other column. I just want to redirect me if I click on the correct column only. Thanks

Comment: not able to understand your issue. by doing above thing only specific column will be hyperlinked and it will take to new window not all.

Comment: i copied the function in click action and change the rowIdx][1] to rowIdx]['RESUMEN'] or rowIdx][10] but when i clicked anywhere not only in column 10 it take to new window

Comment: Thank you. One question, Where i put the css in advanced properties->style?

Comment: in layout panel you have to add resource, where you have to select resource type as CSS and give the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the column name you want to achieve the click action on as  below

```
function(obj) {
   if(obj.category == 'Desired Column'){

 // perform desired click action below
 }
}
```